# Xcode Errors Duplicated on Every Target in Issue Navigator

Tags: xcode, xcode14.3

In Xcode 14.3.1 (and earlier), I have multiple Targets (Debug, Development, Beta and Production). When I'm building for a single target I'll see the error in the Issues Navigator for every target. Anyone run into this and have a solution for removing these duplicate issues? I commented out an import to demonstrate the duplication of the error. I'm building for the Debug target and yet it shows issues on all targets. In addition, this happens on multiple computers, so not a derived data issue (although, I have cleared that).

[image: Duplicate Issue Navigator]

In addition, if I close and re-open Xcode it initially opens with just the one issue being shown, until it re-indexes and then shows the duplicates again.

[image: Non-Duplicate Issue Navigator]

Comment: Thanks for posting this question so I don't have to. Sadly... I have no solution and I think this is new to Xcode 14. I have the exact same issue and it's not "clean derived data" or something.

It initially opens with the one target but then immediately shows the other targets.

Comment: Have you guys tried deleting the other schemes and adding back the schemes?

Comment: Any solution to this?  I have this same error.  Frustrating.

Comment: I finally got around to trying @J.Goce's suggestion, but that did not fix it.